# availableQuestions returning length: 0 inside a function (quiz app)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
let newQuestions = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("questions"));
console.log(newQuestions)

function startGame() {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuestions = [...newQuestions];
    console.log(availableQuestions);
    getNewQuestion();
};

startGame();
```

When `console.log(newQuestions)` is displayed it's okay, but when displayed at `availableQuestions` its not return the array values.

[image: 1]

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```js
let newQuestions = ['a','b'];
console.log(newQuestions)

function startGame() {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuestions = [...newQuestions];
    console.log(availableQuestions);
}

startGame();
```

So the error is **in another part of your code**.

Try searching for "newQuestions" in your file and make sure that its elements don't get removed before `startGame()` is called.

Also keep in mind that JavaScript passes the **reference** to an object when you assign it to a new variable, and not a copy of the object as you might expect. Therefore something like

```
const x = newQuestions;
x.pop();
x.pop();
```

will clear the original `newQuestions`-Array.

Comment: newQuestions is getting the values from the array in another file, I can't change the values like you showed "a", "b". The code in the another file is: window.sessionStorage.setItem("questions", JSON.stringify(questionsByChoices));